# How do I add regions to page variable?

Tags: dashboard

I follow drupal core module dashborad to create a module.

When I visit my custom dashboard page, all block content show:empty.

But I know they shouldn't be.

After check my module code with dashbord.module, I use dpm() to dump the $page in
dashboard_page_build function.

And I found the different bettwen my module and dashbord.module.

In dashbord.module the $page like:
[image]

In my module the $page like :
[image]

The different is :
my module hook_page_build function $page don't have my dashbord region.

But I check dashboard.module manay times without find where to add dashboard regions to the $page.

Does anyone have good idea ?